# Can a custom element be passed an object for the params like the component binding can?

Tags: knockout.js

Can a Knockout [custom element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html) have the params attribute bound to an object like a [Component binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html) can?

For example I have the following component defined:

```
ko.components.register('user-widget', {
    template: '<p><span data-bind = "text:fullName" ></span></p>',
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.fullName = params.firstName + ' ' + params.lastName;
    }
});
```

And the following VM:

```
function VM() {
    this.user = {
        firstName: 'Joe',
        lastName: 'Baker'
    };
}
```

When using a component binding I can pass the user property of the VM directly to the params attribute like so:

```
<div data-bind='component:{name:"user-widget", params:user}'></div>
```

However when using a custom element I have to unbox the user property like so:

```
<user-widget params="firstName:user.firstName, lastName:user.lastName"></user-widget>
```

I tried using a custom element with a component binding like so:

```
<user-widget data-bind='component:{params:user}'></user-widget>
```

Which results in the following error:

> Cannot use the "component" binding on a custom element matching a
>   component

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4o7L4te/4/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you need to change your component to accept a user parameter rather than each separate parameter.

```html
<user-widgetx params='user: user'></user-widgetx>
```

```js
ko.components.register('user-widgetx', {
    template: '<p><span data-bind = "text:fullName" ></span></p>',
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.fullName = params.user.firstName + ' ' + params.user.lastName;
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4o7L4te/5/)

---

I explored the idea of tweaking the binding provider to hook into the parsing code.  I was able to get things to work out.  But I must warn you, this is by all means a hack.  This was testing using Knockout v3.2 and I make no guarantees that this will always work.  At least, until they add in other ways to extend knockout's core functionality.

Looking at the source, I noticed that the `params` parsing code is using knockout's builtin binding parser.  So if we can somehow hook into the parser, we can adjust how the binding strings are interpreted to achieve what we want.

The goal here is to create a new type of binding so the parsed expression is to be treated as the actual binding object.  This could have further uses outside of the component params as well.  That way, we can do this in our bindings/params:

```html
<user-widget params='${user}'></user-widget>
```

Now anything within the `${ }` can be treated as the binding/params object.

```
(function () {
    var originalParseBindingsString = ko.bindingProvider.prototype.parseBindingsString,
        re = /^\$\{(.+)\}$/;

    function extractBindableObject(objExpr, bindingContext, node, options) {
        var objBindingString = '_object: ' + objExpr,
            objGetter = originalParseBindingsString.call(this, objBindingString, bindingContext, node, options),
            obj = objGetter['_object']();
        return objectMap(obj, function (value) {
            return function () { return value; };
        });
    }

    function objectMap(obj, mapper) {
        if (!obj) return obj;
        var result = {};
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
                result[prop] = mapper(obj[prop], prop, obj);
        }
        return result;
    }

    ko.bindingProvider.prototype.parseBindingsString = function (bindingsString, bindingContext, node, options) {
        var m = bindingsString.match(re);
        if (m) {
            return extractBindableObject.call(this, m[1], bindingContext, node, options);
        }
        return originalParseBindingsString.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}());
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t4o7L4te/7/)

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for.  I know I can pass an individual parameter as an object like you've shown.  However, I want to bind the params attribute to a single object like can be done with the component binding.

Comment: I'm afraid what you're looking for is just not possible currently.  Looking at the source, custom components will specifically look for a `params` attribute. It does however use the binding provider to parse the bindings so if you wanted, you could come up with a new binding scheme so you can instead use the passed in object as the parsed bindings.

Comment: Sorry scratch that, it looks like the binding provider cannot be hooked in to. in this case

Comment: Can you think of a way to get a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) to do this?

Comment: The thing is, the `params` attribute of the custom component does not follow the usual binding behaviors. It's simply a mapping between keys and values for the parameters passed to the component view model. Anyway, it appears it is possible to override binding provider methods to hook into. I'll see what I can do about this.

Comment: This is the correct answer, you don't have to unbox the observable:, use params="user: user"  e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/Lkw1qfdj/

Answer (score 0):

If someone comes here looking for a workaround for this issue I solved it like so:

When registering your component make your function viewmodel constructor just to receive a whole object that contains all the parameters you need:

```
function gridViewModel(params) {
   var self = this;
   var gridConfig = params.gridConfig;
   self.data = gridConfig.data;
   self.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(0);
   self.pageSize = gridConfig.pageSize || 5;
   ...
}

ko.components.register("grid-widget", {
   template: { element: 'ko-grid'},
   viewModel: gridViewModel    
});
```

Then you can use your custom element like this:

```
   <grid-widget params='gridConfig: gridConfig'></grid-widget>
```

Where the first **gridConfig** is the param your constructor function will receive on
**params.gridConfig** and the second one is an object you have in your nearest viewModel context.